# How to remove a class property which is a list of another class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, list, class, generic-list

I need to remove an item form a generic list, which is actually a list of of another class, in VB.net ?

Below is my class, how to achieve the following?

1. From the settings class, I want to remove the section that has the name as "Three":
2. next I want to return only the section that has the name as "Three" and not the other section values?

```
Public Class Settings

    Public Property Sections As List(Of Section)

End Class

Public Class Section

    Public Property Name As String
 
    Public Property Age As Int
 
    Public Property addesss As String

End Class
```

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation of the `List` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1)?

Comment: Yes, It says to use remove or removeAll . I am very new to VB.net so not able to achieve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RemoveAll` method allows you to find items that match specific criteria and remove them:

```vb
mySettings.Sections.RemoveAll(Function(s) s.Name = "Three")
```

The argument is a lambda expression that matches `Section` objects with a `Name` property equal to "Three".